I have tried some examples in PYLTSpice which is the toolchain of python to control LTSpice
I have done my coding in VSCode:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyLTSpice.LTSpice_RawRead import LTSpiceRawRead
LTR = LTSpiceRawRead(r'Example3.raw')
print(LTR.get_trace_names())
print(LTR.get_raw_property())
V001    = LTR.get_trace("V(n001)")
V002    = LTR.get_trace("V(n002)")
x       = LTR.get_trace('time')
steps   = LTR.get_steps()
fig = plt.figure()
for step in range(len(steps)):
    plt.plot(x.get_time_axis(step), V001.get_wave(step), label="Vin",color="blue")
    plt.plot(x.get_time_axis(step), V002.get_wave(step), label="Vout",color="red")
plt.legend(fontsize=9)
plt.xlabel("time[s]")
plt.ylabel("voltage[V]")
plt.show()

And The error it shows in terminal:
from PyLTSpice.LTSpice_RawRead import LTSpiceRawRead
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyLTSpice.LTSpice_RawRead'
Could anyone tell what issue that I am facing and How could I fix this.
